# Xamarin/C# Select only one Radio Button from custom list view

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, radio-button, baseadapter

Im using Xamarin to create my App. I have a custom ListView atm. with Radiobuttons in it. These Radiobuttons are clickable, but every single one of them is (multiple).

The result that I want should work like the following: Only 1 can be checked at the time. There are some Java solutions, but they don´t help me at all. Thanks in advance.

This is how I create my Listview

```
        mListView = FindViewById<Android.Widget.ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);

        mItems = new List<Artikel>();
        mItems.Add(new Artikel() { Name = "X", Amount = 50 });
        mItems.Add(new Artikel() { Name = "Y", Amount = 300 });
        mItems.Add(new Artikel() { Name = "Z", Amount = 80 });
        mItems.Add(new Artikel() { Name = "A", Amount = 174 });

        MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);
        mListView.Adapter = adapter;
```

Artikel.cs

```
    class Artikel
    {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

MyListViewAdapter.cs

```
    private List<Artikel> mItems;
    private Context mContext;


    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Artikel> items)
    {
        mItems = items;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mItems.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Artikel this[int position]
    {
        get { return mItems[position]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);
        }
        TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Name);
        txtName.Text = mItems[position].Name;

        TextView txtamount = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Amount);
        txtamount.Text = mItems[position].Amount.ToString();


        return row;  
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see where you add the radio-button into the ListView. Can you update your post with that code? . Usually to do an exclusive selection of Radiobutton in Android you need to use a RadioGroup.

Comment: I added the radio-button in the custom layout of the list-view. How would it work with a RadioGroup, could you explain it please?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, when you want your RadioButtons to be exclusive (only one selected by context) you can wrap them in a RadioGroup.

Imagine this is the ListView item custom Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

    <RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rb1"
            android:text="Option 1" />
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rb2"
            android:text="Option 2" />
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rb3"
            android:text="Option 3" />
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rb4"
            android:text="Option 4" />
    </RadioGroup>    
</LinearLayout>
```

By adding the `RadioGroup` users will be able to select only one RadioButton from each `ListView` item

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. The Problem is that each row of the Listview gets all the radiobuttons.

Comment: That code is exactly what is supposed to do. So now based on your comment I understand you want a single RadioButton selection within the whole ListView items. is this correct?